# Мобильное приложение работает на xampp но не работает на linux

Tags: php, java, android

Мобильное приложение использует backend сделанный на фраймворке Slim  На xampp  работает на linux не работает Мобильное приложение пишет на linux valley error при парсинге json

Comment: Значит действительно "ошибочное значение" - у вас в json-данных подаваемых на вход, поступило недопустимое значение в одном из полей. Просто посмотрите глазами на то, что сервер вам выдал  - возможно проблема с кодировками, например.

Comment: Правьте ваш вопрос. Не нужно по одной строчке писать в комментариях.

Comment: Где это можно посмотреть что выдаёт мой сервер ?

Comment: У меня настроики в mysql кодировка соединения utf8mb4_unicode_ci Unicode (utf8) таблицы имеют latin1_swedish_ci 
В андроид студио global encoding utf-8 Proect encoding windows 1252
php файлы utf-8 
linux php.ini utf-8 xamp php.ini utf-8  
кодировка сервера UTF-8 на линукс и ксамп одинаковая